# Python ggplot Plot Save Method Syntax?

Tags: ipython, python-ggplot

Have tried several iterative versions, based on the error message prompts, to save a ggplot to file using either the pixels or inches method:

```
ggsave(filename="nlrundiff.jpg", width=4, height=4, units='in', plot=plt)
```

No success in either case, the resulting error message excerpt is as follows:

```
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ggplot/utils/ggutils.pyc in ggsave(filename, plot, device, format, path, scale, width, height, units, dpi, limitsize, **kwargs)
        118     from_inch = {"in":lambda x:x,"cm":lambda x: x * 2.54, "mm":lambda x: x * 2.54 * 10}
        119 
    --> 120     w, h = figure.get_size_inches()
        121     issue_size = False
        122     if width is None:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_size_inches'
```

Is this a input syntax error on my part or a Python ggplot bug?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `ggsave(...)` without specifying the ggplot object or printing it beforehand is not supported (but the above is a [bug](https://github.com/yhat/ggplot/issues/338) and should print a user readable message).

So, either print the ggplot object with `gg.draw()` or `print(gg)` and then call `ggsave(...)` like you did above OR pass in the ggplot-object: `ggsave(gg, filename=...)`.

Comment: Using this example, the file is created but is completely blank  print(a)
ggsave(filename="nlrundiff.jpg")

Comment: Can you post the full code to reproduce the error or a example which shows the problem?

Comment: I decided to pursue another route to a fix.